# get_option & update_option for multiple input fields with same name wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
<?php
        $vArgs = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'offset' => 0,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby'  => 'date',
            'post_type' => 'video-list',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => 0
        );
        $video_list = get_posts($vArgs);
        if ($video_list) {
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($video_list as $video_item) {?>
            <li>
                <div class="admin_video_views_val bottom_view_col">
                    <input type="text" name="addon_post_views_count_meta[<?php echo $count; ?>]" id="addon_post_views_count_meta[<?php echo $count; ?>]" class="get_addon_post_views_count" value="<?php echo $post_views_countnew;?>">
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
            $count++; 
            }
        } ?>
  </ul>
```

I created admin menu and am showing all posts views count there in input fields values with this code:

```
<input type="text" name="addon_post_views_count_meta[<?php echo $count; ?>]" id="addon_post_views_count_meta[<?php echo $count; ?>]" class="get_addon_post_views_count" value="<?php $post_views_count = get_post_meta( $video_item->ID, 'post_views_count', true );if ( ! empty( $post_views_count ) ) {echo $post_views_count;}else{echo $post_views_countnew;}?>">
```

How you see I put input text fields it means that count needs to be editable by user. I wrote something like this but it doesn't work properly, it doesn't save the option but should do, how can I do this?

```
if(isset($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'])){
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta']); $i++){
         if($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'][$i] >= 0){
             $post_views_countnew = esc_attr($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'][$i]);   
             update_option($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'][$i], $post_views_countnew);               
         }
    }
}

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta']); $i++){
    if($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'][$i] >= 0){
        $post_views_countnew = get_option($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'][$i]);
        echo $post_views_countnew;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using brackets for a normal input? Just remove the **[** **]**  in the name tag and make it so you could do something like this: $_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta' . $i]

Comment: in this case how can I check this if(isset($_POST['addon_post_views_count_meta'])) ? @Naruto

Comment: You put the isset in your loop

Comment: as my input fields with same name and id are many that's why I used [] to make them as array and my isset condition worked but now when I removed brackets it doesn't work @Naruto

Comment: name="addon_post_views_count_meta<?php echo $count; ?>"

Comment: can you please provide whole code with your change? cause I tried what you suggested it doesn't work @Naruto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91073/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-naruto).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91095/discussion-between-aidaghazaryan-and-naruto).